# Is there a way to slice a dataframe when the characteristic variable has non-printable characters?

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, csv

I imported multiple CSV files from census data. I was able to successfully bring in the files and append the three files (axis 0) one on top of the other. I was able to put the data into a dataframe successfully too. But every time I try to slice the dataframe using the categorical variable in this case the country name, it doesn't work. I think it's because the csv files had non-printable characters. So I added some code that I thought removed the non-printable characters, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

# Define a function to remove non-printable characters from a string
def remove_non_printable(text):
    # Use regex to remove non-printable characters
    printable_pattern = re.compile(r'[\x00-\x08\x0E-\x1F\x7F]+')
    return printable_pattern.sub('', text)

# Apply the function to each cell in the DataFrame
cleaned_df = df.applymap(remove_non_printable)

# Display the cleaned DataFrame
print(cleaned_df)
```

Output

```
     Year                                              Label Total_Population
0    2010                                             Total:       38,674,773
1    2010                                            Europe:        4,847,078
2    2010                                   Northern Europe:          938,120
3    2010              United Kingdom (inc. Crown Depende...          684,806
4    2010                  United Kingdom, excluding Engl...          252,267
..    ...                                                ...              ...
486  2021                                          Venezuela          457,958
487  2021                                Other South America           38,509
488  2021                                  Northern America:          828,196
489  2021                                             Canada          818,916
490  2021                             Other Northern America            9,280

[491 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using `df['Label'] = df['Label'].str.replace(...)`

Comment: Please make a [reproducible pandas example](/q/20109391/4518341). We need to see how you're trying to do the slicing, and if that all looks good, we need to see the actual data so we can test solutions. For more background, see [mre]. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: @wjandrea I did not try that code since I used the function to clean the non-printable characters in the dataframe. I can share where I sourced the data from? It's from a US Census website. I downloaded the data as a CSV file https://data.census.gov/table/ACSDT5YAIAN2010.B05006?q=Foregin+Born+US+citizens&moe=false

Comment: @Sean We just need a sample. Please do read the links I posted.

Comment: @wjandrea Thank you. I read the link; forgive me, I'm new. I understand, but I don't know how to illustrate the non-printable characters in the data. I'm just trying to figure out how to create an example showing the spaces in the source data.

Comment: @Sean It's covered in the link: *"For getting runnable code, `df.to_dict` is often useful"*. (I actually wrote that part myself btw)